# Parsing JSON with GSON error

Tags: java, json, gson

I've got this Json response from a server

```
[
  {
    "genre": [
        "2",
        "17"
    ],
    "terms": {
        "ID Criteria": [
            "Photo ID",
            "Over 21s"
        ],
        "Dress Code criteria": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "images": [
        "http://www.cool.eu/fixr/images/events/d_1000/size800_lasers-2520cd46e8107e.jpg",
        "http://www.cool.eu/fixr/images/events/d_1000/size800_fabric-4520cd48414f19.jpg"
    ],
    "codes": [
        {
            "code": "HC0989",
            "price": "8.00"
        }
    ],
    "id": "1",
    "live": "1",
    "venueId": "1",
    "title": "Eden Project",
    "subTitle": "",
    "date": "2013-08-24",
    "openTime": "Saturday 24th August",
    "closeTime": "10:30 - 05:30",
    "price": "1.00",
    "bookingFee": "1.50",
    "standby": "0",
    "djs": "Tim Cullen, Santero, Adam K, Matt May, R3wire, Dj Ez, Shame Khoe",
    "presenter": "",
    "overview": "As with any top DJ these days, it’s hard to pigeon-hole someone into one specific sound/genre, but Tim’s sets would perhaps be best described as ‘chunky tech-house grooves, spliced with main room progressive house synths’. This warm, uplifting and energet",
    "notes": "",
    "cutOff": "",
    "firstCutOff": "2013-08-24 11:30:00",
    "secondCutOff": "2013-08-24 00:00:00",
    "autoCutOff": "2013-08-25 02:30:00",
    "tickets": "20",
    "payment": "0"
},
{
    "genre": [
        "2",
        "17"
    ],
    "terms": {
        "ID Criteria": [
            "Photo ID",
            "Over 21s"
        ],
        "Dress Code criteria": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "images": [
        "http://www.cool.eu/fixr/images/events/d_1000/size800_fabric-2520cd771cfd88.jpg"
    ],
    "codes": [
        {
            "code": "HC0989",
            "price": "8.00"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2",
    "live": "1",
    "venueId": "1",
    "title": "Eden Project",
    "subTitle": "",
    "date": "2013-10-19",
    "openTime": "Thursday 19th September",
    "closeTime": "10:30 - 05:30",
    "price": "10.00",
    "bookingFee": "1.50",
    "standby": "0",
    "djs": "Tim Cullen, Santero, Adam K, Matt May, R3wire, Dj Ez, Shame Khoe",
    "presenter": "",
    "overview": "As with any top DJ these days, it’s hard to pigeon-hole someone into one specific sound/genre, but Tim’s sets would perhaps be best described as ‘chunky tech-house grooves, spliced with main room progressive house synths’. This warm, uplifting and energet",
    "notes": "",
    "cutOff": "",
    "firstCutOff": "2013-09-19 11:30:00",
    "secondCutOff": "2013-09-19 00:00:00",
    "autoCutOff": "2013-09-20 02:30:00",
    "tickets": "20",
    "payment": "0"
  }
]
```

And I've created this object

```
public class EventDetails {

@SerializedName("id")
public String id;

@SerializedName("title")
public String name;

@SerializedName("price")
public String price;    

@SerializedName("bookingFee")
public String booking_fee;

@SerializedName("standby")
public int isStandBy;

@SerializedName("subTitle")
public String show;

@SerializedName("closeTime")
public String time;

@SerializedName("openTime")
public String date;

@SerializedName("date")
public String eventDate;

//@SerializedName("genre")
public String[] genre;

@SerializedName("venueId")
public String venue_id;

@SerializedName("overview")
public String overview;

@SerializedName("djs")
public String presenter;

@SerializedName("terms")
public String terms;

@SerializedName("firstCutOff")
public String firstCutOff;

@SerializedName("secondCutOff")
public String secondCutOff;

@SerializedName("autoCutOff")
public String thirdCutOff;

@SerializedName("tickets")
public String tickets;

//@SerializedName("images")
public String[] image_url;

//@SerializedName("codes")
public String[] promoCodes; 
 }
```

I'm trying to use a GSON to parse this like I have done on other projects with this code.

```
String result = httpRequest(params);
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<EventDetails>>(){}.getType();              
List<EventDetails> data = gson.fromJson(result, collectionType);
```

I keep getting this exception and not sure what the solution is

```
08-17 19:39:00.835: W/System.err(29478): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Java objects for those nested and then add to your EventDetails class.

For example codes `"codes": [
        {
            "code": "HC0989",
            "price": "8.00"
        }
    ],`

You can create a class

```
public class Codes{
    public String code;
    public String price;
}
```

then add to your EventDetails

```
public Codes[] codes;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
@SerializedName("terms")
public String terms;
```

Your JSON has:

```
"terms": {
    "ID Criteria": [
        "Photo ID",
        "Over 21s"
    ],
    "Dress Code criteria": [
        ""
    ]
},
```

"terms" is not a `String`. It's an Object (specifically one with two fields that are arrays), and Gson is telling you that.

Comment: I've just commented out that serialize statement but I still get same error

Comment: And a similar error also applies to the 'codes' field.  You need to declare these as object fields, where the object is of a class that has the appropriate fields; in the case of 'codes' it will need to be a list of the appropriate class.

Comment: Yes, I noted that after your first post right now I only id and venueId as serialized and commented everything else out to see it it works but I still get same error.

Comment: Most of your `@SerializedName` annotations are redundant and don't actually do anything; Gson matches on the actual field name. The only time you use that annotation is when the fieldname in JSON and the fieldname in your Java class differs. So yes ... if a field in Java still doesn't match your JSON in terms of type, you're going to keep getting errors until it does.

Comment: Changing the names to match the fields in my JSON did the trick. Please edit your answer to highlight this for the benefit of others.